# Icon not displayed in taskbar for Windows 10 UWP app

Tags: icons, uwp

I've set various Visual Assets in my Package.appxmanifest i.e.

- Square 71x71 Logo
- Square 150x150 Logo
- Square 310x310 Logo
- Square 44x44 Logo
- Store Logo

I don't have any images defined for Wide 310x150 Logo and for the Badge Logo.

When installed on the phone, it displays the logo as expected when the app is listed in the application list and when pinned to the start screen.

When installed on my laptop, it displays the logo as expected when the app is pinned to the Start menu.

And yet when I run this on my laptop the app in desktop mode, it displays the default square with a cross in my taskbar (or when using alt-tab).

Do I have to set up an icon somewhere else or do I need to setup another visual asset that's not listed?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

See Bart's answer below for solution but here are a few useful links I found:

- [Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx#asset_types)
- [Tile and toast visual assets (Windows Runtime apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/hh781198.aspx)
- [How to generate and manage app visual assets for Windows AND Windows Phone with ease using Photoshop actions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2015/02/11/how-to-generate-and-manage-app-visual-assets-for-windows-and-windows-phone-with-ease-using-photoshop-actions.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you used the default Windows 10 UWP template, these assets are added.

[image]

The `Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png` icon is shown in the taskbar and when switching between apps. If you remove this file, Windows normally falls back to the Square44x44Logo.png file (at least on my machine).

Comment: Thanks Bart. That worked a charm. Didn't spot this file until you mentioned it :). I will fill all of them for now and will research it further as I'd like to know what they mean by unplated and targetsize as all I was using was the scaled asset for the 44x44.